# Como tirar width da div quando minimizar tela - Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right: -15px; width:200px">
</div>
```

Porem como estou trabalhando com bootstrap eu queria retirar esse width caso a minha tela fique menor, pra que minha div não fique com tamanho fixo, alguem sabe como posso estar fazendo isso?

Comment: Quer tirar apenas dessa div específica ou de todas com classe `.col-md-1`?

Comment: tenho 5 divs com a classe col-md-2, na minha tela as colunas ficam bem pequenas então usei o width para aumentar a largura, mas quando eu expando a tela ai a coluna fica maior, entretanto como deixei width fixo a responsividade nao funciona.  entao queria deixar o width somente quando minha tela nao esta expandida ou minimizada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer esse controle com jQuery. Este código irá aplicar `width=100%` quando a tela for menor do que "200px" e `width=200px` quando for igual ou maior que "200px" a todas as divs com a class `.col-md-1`:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
   window.innerWidth < 200 ? div_width = '100%' : div_width = '200px';
   $('.col-md-1').css('width',div_width);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Procure usar o sistema de grid do bootstrap [veja aqui](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/), usando ela você não precisa se preocupar com largura nem altura dos componentes que está usando, sem contar que o seu site fique responsivo.

Caso você utilize o sistema de grid, evite quebrar a lógica da biblioteca, causando overflow de tamanho do item através de inserção do seletor width ou height.

Caso não saiba ou não queira usar o sistema de grid, aconselho você a usar os seletores de altura e largura, sempre como percentual.

Exemplo: `width:200%`

Estava recentemente aprendendo a trabalhar com o grid do bootstrap e talvez seja uma boa mostra aqui.

Esse código está em EcmaScript pois estava desenvolvendo junto com ReactJS, mas ignore esse detalhe para não complicar.

> ```
>  <header style={cssHeader}>
>     <Grid fluid={true} style={cssGrid}>
>       <Row style={cssRow}>
>         <Col lg={2} md={4} xs={12} style={cssCol}>
>           <h1 >  Logo </h1>
>         </Col>
>         <Col lg={6} md={8} xs={6} style={cssCol}>
>           <h1 > Soluções Inteligentes </h1>
>         </Col>
>         <Col lg={4} md={12} xs={6} style={cssCol}>
>           <h1 > XXX</h1>
>         </Col>
>       </Row>
>     </Grid>
>   </header>
> ```

Perceba que é possível manipular todos os elementos dentro do grid, além de ser possível criar infinitos grids.

Nesse meu exemplo, eu testei diferentes tamanhos dos elementos de acordo com a tela do usuário, então ele mostra os componentes `logo` , `Soluções Inteligentes` e `xxx` de diferentes formas conforme o tamanho dispositivo que o usuário está acessando, nesse caso o computador, tablet ou celular, nessa ordem.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o grid próprio do bootstrap:

col-xs-"**e um numero até 12**" utilizar a class xs para a orientação em celulares

col-sm-"**e um numero até 12**" utilizar a class sm para a orientação em tablets

col-md-"**e um numero até 12**" utilizar a class md para a orientação em desktops pequenos

col-lg-"**e um numero até 12**" utilizar a class lg para a orientação em desktops medios e grandes

Exemplos:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> //crie uma div com o tamanho máximo

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-12>
        <p> Primeiro paragrafo></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-12>
        <p> Segundo paragrafo></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-12>
        <p> Terceiro paragrafo></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Crie os demais objetos que estiverem dentro da sua div principal sempre tendo em mente que para permanecerem em linha e os seus tamanhos são relativos ao tipo de classe e o tamanho escolhido. Caso queira eles em linha mantenha a soma de todos os objetos com o total de 12, ou com o limite que vc escolher na sua div principal(*Lembrando que o máximo é 12*).

Assim suas paginas vão automaticamente se adequar com o tamanho da pagina. Espero ter ajudado.